# Play base64 audio string from Azure Blob service REST api with Javascript/Phonegap

Tags: javascript, audio, cordova, azure-storage

Im having trouble playing an audio file (.aac) that is stored as a bae64 encoded string in Azure Blob Storage from javascript.

I have the following scenario:

- A mobile app (PhoneGap) which records audio to an .aac file and stores it in localstorage. The file same is small (<250kb)
- The file get's converted to a base64 encoded string and uploaded to my blob storage account through an jquery ajax call (see UPLOAD_CODE) below by using the Blob Service REST api. See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135733.aspx) for details on the BLOB Service rest api.
- When i download the file manually through the browser i can see the base64 encoded string which starts witch "data:application/octet-stream;base64,AAAA....."

UPLOAD_CODE snippet:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "PUT",
  data: requestData,
  processData: false,
  beforeSend: function (xhr) 
              {
               xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-type', 'BlockBlob');
               },
               tryCount: 0,
               retryLimit: NUMBER_OF_RETRIES,
               success: successcallback,
               error: errorcallback
   });
```

At this point all is well. I am stuck at playback of the file from the storage api. I can access the file through the url but now i want a user to be able to listen to the uploaded audio.

I've been thinking along the following solutions which i haven't been able to get working yet:

A.  Use phonegap media class and pass in the url to the base64 encoded string and start playing (streaming) audio.

B. Download base64 string, convert to audio file in javascript and start playback.

C. Upload the file in Blob storage as an actual aac file instead of a base64 encoded string so playback starts when opening the url through, for example, the browser.

D. ... ?

In what way can I turn any of these scenario's into a working solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by uploading the file as a byte[] instead of base64 encoded string. The file get's stored as an .aac audio file in blob storage and can be played directly from storage.

For uploading i used the following code:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function (evt) {

if (evt.target.readyState === FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2

    var RETRY_TIMEOUT_SECONDS = 5;
    var NUMBER_OF_RETRIES = 3;

    var requestData = new Uint8Array(evt.target.result);

    $.ajax({
             url: url,
             type: "PUT",
             data: requestData,
             processData: false,
             beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                                xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-type', 'BlockBlob');
                            },
             tryCount: 0,
             retryLimit: NUMBER_OF_RETRIES,
             success: function (data, status) {
                                console.log(status);
                            },
              error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
                      if (xhr.status === 403) {
                                    console.log("Access denied, the assigned upload  time has been exeeded");
                                } else {
                                    this.tryCount += 1;
                                    if (this.tryCount <= this.retryLimit) {
                                        console.log("Retrying transmission");
                                        setTimeout($.ajax(this), RETRY_TIMEOUT_SECONDS * 1000);
                                        return;
                                    }
                                }
                                console.log(desc);
                                console.log(err);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                };

  // Read the file as a byte[] 
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(dbFile);
```